# Amazon EC2 Beanstalk Laravel showing code instead of displaying the page

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First time working with Laravel and Beanstalk.  I loaded my code, and the home page said permission denied, when I added /public, it said not found.

After some searching I updated my `httpd.config` file's DocumentRoot from `/var/www/html/` to `/var/www/html/timers/public`, did a 'sudo service httpd restart' and now it's displaying the following unformatted text in on my EC2 Homepage

> (http://craftaxethrowingtimers-env.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

:

> */ define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true)); /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Register The Auto Loader |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for | our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it | into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual | loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax. | */ require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Turn On The Lights |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights. | This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it | will load up this application so that we can run it and send | the responses back to the browser and delight our users. | */ $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Run The Application |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request | through the kernel, and send the associated response back to | the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative | and wonderful application we have prepared for them. | */ $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class); $response = $kernel->handle( $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() ); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Comment: what exactly your browser page showing?  401? 404?

Comment: exactly the highlighted output above

Answer (score 0):

If there is permission issue, give the permission to the apache server of your new document root as follow,

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/timers/public
```